# Trying to send an <a> that includes a serialized PHP array through JSON-encoded AJAX

Tags: php, json, ajax, serialization, escaping

I have a link that looks like this being generated in a php file called through AJAX:

```
<a href="/path/to/my/file.php?data=a:4:{s:4:"var1";i:1;s:4:"var2";i:2;s:4:"var3";i:3;s:4:"var4";i:4;}"></a>
```

To get this:

```
<?php
$other_info = '<a href="' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '?data=' . serialize($my_array) . '">Download</a>');

$retval = array('link' => $other_info);

echo json_encode($retval);
?>
```

I'm having trouble handling this on the front end. I tried enclosing it like this:

```
$other_info = htmlspecialchars($other_info);
```

but I can't get it to come through in a way I can handle on the front. It seems to enclose it in an additional set of double-quotation marks. How can I escape it out?

> EDIT: I forgot to add this line, I apologize: $retval = array('link'
>   => $other_info); It has been added to the code.

Comment: Query strings, being what they are, will require that you do some minimal manipulation unless you use them in a straightforward way. It *looks* like you're trying to send JSON, but if it is JSON it will not validate. http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a way to do it. On the PHP side:

```
$other_info = htmlspecialchars(serialize($_REQUEST));
```

and on the javascript side:

```
var oi = resp.link
oi = '<a href="/path/to/my/file.php?data=' + oi + '">Download</a>'
```

That fixed it.